# Can integers and strings be concatenated in ArnoldC?

Tags: string-concatenation

I'm making an implementation of 99 bottles of beer in ArnoldC to list in Rosetta Code. I'm hoping to get the integers and the strings that are supposed to be on the same line to print on the same line, but I'm unable to do so. Can integers and strings be concatenated in ArnoldC? If so, how can that be accomplished?

Through trial and error, I've tried:

- TALK TO THE HAND bottles "bottles of beer on the wall"
- TALK TO THE HAND bottles,"bottles of beer on the wall"
- TALK TO THE HAND bottles+"bottles of beer on the wall"
- TALK TO THE HAND bottles
  TALK TO THE HAND "\tbottles of beer on the wall"
- TALK TO THE HAND bottles
  TALK TO THE HAND "\t bottles of beer on the wall"
- TALK TO THE HAND bottles
  TALK TO THE HAND "\rbottles of beer on the wall"
- TALK TO THE HAND bottles
  TALK TO THE HAND "\r bottles of beer on the wall"
- TALK TO THE HAND bottles
  TALK TO THE HAND "\nbottles of beer on the wall"
- TALK TO THE HAND bottles
  TALK TO THE HAND "\n bottles of beer on the wall"

Here's my code:

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE is0
YOU SET US UP @NO PROBLEMO
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE bottles
YOU SET US UP 99
STICK AROUND is0
TALK TO THE HAND bottles
TALK TO THE HAND "bottles of beer on the wall"
TALK TO THE HAND bottles
TALK TO THE HAND "bottles of beer"
TALK TO THE HAND "Take one down, pass it around"
GET TO THE CHOPPER bottles
HERE IS MY INVITATION bottles
GET DOWN 1
ENOUGH TALK
TALK TO THE HAND bottles
TALK TO THE HAND "bottles of beer on the wall"
GET TO THE CHOPPER is0
HERE IS MY INVITATION bottles
LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET 0
ENOUGH TALK
CHILL
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

**For example, I'd like:**

```
99
bottles of beer on the wall
```

to instead be printed as

`99 bottles of beer on the wall`

But any attempts to do so lead to me getting syntax errors. For example, when I attempt TALK TO THE HAND bottles"\nbottles of beer on the wall", I get:

> Exception in thread "main" org.parboiled.errors.ParsingException:
>   WHAT THE FUCK DID I DO WRONG:
>
> Invalid input '"', expected A..Z,
>   a..z, 0..9, '\t', '\r', ' ' or '\n' (line 7, pos 25):
>
> TALK TO THE
>   HAND bottles"\nbottles of beer on the wall"
>                           ^
>
> at org.arnoldc.ArnoldParser.parse(ArnoldParser.scala:203)
>
> at org.arnoldc.ArnoldGenerator.generate(ArnoldGenerator.scala:10)
>
> at
>   org.arnoldc.ArnoldC$.main(ArnoldC.scala:21)
>
> at
>   org.arnoldc.ArnoldC.main(ArnoldC.scala)
>
> Error: Could not find or
>   load main class code

Please excuse me if you think I formatted any of this question weirdly, I couldn't find out how to format it to not have what looks like blank lines between each line where I wanted.

By the way, I'm using https://tio.run/#arnoldc to run my code.